# Return a value from a class and use it in main Form1.cs - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, label

Is it possible to create a variable named `score` and use it globally across classes?

For example: Create it in `Form1.cs` for example and be still able to use it within `ball.cs`?

I have a collision detection between a brick and the ball in my Breakout-type game.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ball.moveBall();
    ball.collideWall();
    ball.hitPaddle(paddle.PaddleRec);
    ball.hitBrick(brick.BrickRec);
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

I want to use the following line of code to add a score for every time the ball hits a brick. `lblScore.Text = Convert.ToString(score);`

So that basically when the ball hits a brick then the score will be displayed in the label named lblScore.

Here is what I have in my ball class (in a file named ball.cs)

```
public void hitBrick(Rectangle[,] brickRec)
{
    if (ballRec.IntersectsWith(brickRec[0,0]))
    {
        ySpeed *= -1;
        xSpeed *= -1;
        brickRec[0, 0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        score += 10;   
     }
     if (ballRec.IntersectsWith(brickRec[1,0]))
     {
        ySpeed *= -1;
        xSpeed *= -1;
        brickRec[1, 0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        score += 20;
     }
     if (ballRec.IntersectsWith(brickRec[2,0]))
     {
        ySpeed *= -1;
        xSpeed *= -1;
        brickRec[2, 0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        score += 30;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `score` as `static` variable in your main form `Form1.cs`; which will have a global access point like

```
public static int score = 0;
```

Comment: But then my hitBrick function (in ball.cs) will not recognise the variable score.

Comment: It will, you need to access it like `Form1.score` in your ball.cs;